# AppleScript returns error -600 when executed from ssh

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

I got an AppleScript error -600 when I execute it from ssh.

Here's the scenario:

I have two account - accountA & accountB. Both of them are logged in. but as i could only show the desktop of one of them, I showed accountA. Then I open an terminal and ssh to accountB to run such a simple AppleScript

```
tell application "Finder"
  activate
end tell
```

Then returns the error

```
test.scpt: execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn't running. (-600)
```

But if I show the desktop of accountB and ssh from another mac, the execution is success. Show the desktop of accountB from VNC could also work, but might fail again in several hours after the connection is set up.

So I think the key point is to show desktop to make it work from ssh. But I don't know why it will also fail after several hours from VNC connection.

Is anyone has idea about the root reason of it?

And one more to add, i think this problem is related with os, it should be fine on os 10.7, but when we upgrade it to 10.8.4/10.9, error comes.

Comment: You talk about error code 600 (in the title and the question) and -600 (in the error message).  Which one is it?  It can't be both, and they're two different errors.

Comment: @Eric it's -600, i have edited the question